# How to document overridden methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I already document an iOS-App and need to describe a overridden method from the parentclass `UIViewController` provided by Apple.

But *Doxygen* is not showing the method in the documentation.

Comment: Problem solved. I just forgot to set EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS = YES

Comment: BTW: I think that it is a good idea to put overridden methods into the interface, too, if they have been public in the superclass' interface.